# Unable to upgrade WSS_Search_ServerName database

Tags: powershell, upgrade, database

I have got the following error in SharePoint 2010 Central Admin:

> The following databases require upgrade because their versions are
>   older than the backwards compatible range:  WSS_Search_SERVERNAME.

I tried to upgrade as it was sugested using:

```
Upgrade-SPContentDatabase [guid]
```

but I got the error

> Database could not be found.

I also tried:

```
Get-SPContentDatabase | ?{$_.NeedsUpgrade -eq $true} | Upgrade-SPContentDatabase
```

which returned nothing. Then I ran:

```
psconfig -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -wait
```

and got the following exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: The neverStarted argument is invalid.
at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskBase.OnTaskStop(TaskResult result, String message, String extendedMessage)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.UpgradeBootstrapTask.OnTaskSto p(TaskResult result, String message, String extendedMessage)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCl eanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, C ontextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

I cleared the config cache and re-ran it, but again the same exception.

Could you please help? What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The search database is not a content database. You need to upgrade using the SharePoint 2010 Farm Configuration Wizard. I would run that and see where it gets you and then you can find any errors in the upgrade logs.

Here is a link to help.
http://www.justanothertechnologyguy.com/2011/11/databases-require-upgrade-or-not.html

Excerpt:

> •Open a command box in ‘run as administrator’ mode.
>
> •Navigate to the
>   bin directory of the SharePoint root. C:\Program Files\Common
>   Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\BIN
>
> •Run the following
>   command:     `PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd
>    applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures`

Comment: How long will be the downtime?

Comment: Could be anywhere from 30 minutes to 6 hours depending on your server farm size and the size of your database..